# Python - notation for redundant lambda parameters

Tags: python, lambda, parameters, notation

I am trying to build a function

```
f(x, y, z)
```

where neither *x* nor *y* have any impact on the result. Nonetheless, they must be passed to the function, as the passing is done by a library. I would like to:

- solve this using a *lambda* expression, and
- ensure that anyone reading my code will immediately know that *x* and *y* are redundant.

As I have gathered, using the underscore character for redundant return values from multiple-value-returning functions is common practice, e.g.

```
a, _, c, d, _, _ = return_six_things(),
```

however, trying

```
f = lambda _, _, z: some_operation(z)
```

crashes with the exception warning the author about using 'duplicate arguments' (two underscore characters).

Are there any other options?

P.S. to avoid the XY problem, the reason I want to use lambdas is to save a few source code characters. I would love to use them anyway, but declaring that "these parameters will not be used" is more important for me.

Comment: what do you mean, `the passing is done by a library`?

Comment: I think this is a well defined problem for SO, but would probably flag this in code review.  Use of a lambda here to save a few characters is sacrificing clarity for succinctness imo

Comment: @anon01 I have a library function called 'apply_fn_to_some_objects(fn)'. I intend to call 'apply_fn_to_some_objects(lambda _, __, z: some_operation(z))'.

Comment: `apply_fn_to_some_objects(my_fun, *my_fun_args, **my_fun_kwargs)` won't work?

Comment: @anon01 I vainly tried to express the fact that I _want_ to use the lambda as opposed to _needing_ to use the lambda. Whatever 'succinctness' is, I crave it. One-lining expressions is a joy I indulge myself in regularly.

Comment: @anon01 'apply_fn_to_some_objects(fn)' accepts a single parameter, and that is 'fn'. Trying something like that out would result in an 'unexpected argument error' or something similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd use a double underscore (`__`) for the second unused argument:

```py
f = lambda _, __, z: some_operation(z)
```

Comment: oh the double underscore! Completely evaded me, this is exactly what I was looking for. Thx

Answer (score 1):

Options:

```py
# pass in z as a keyward argument
# like this: f(x,y,z=1)
f = lambda *_,z: some_operation(z)

#Or:
# pass in any number of arguments and only use the last argument 
f = lambda *z: some_operation(z[-1])
```

Comment: For the first option, you need to call the function like this: f(1,2,z=3)